# Issue with Asynchronous Behavior in JavaScript: console.log not Displaying Data Inside request.onload Function, and Problem with Session Storage

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, debugging, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on a web application where I have a login function that sends a POST request to my server to authenticate the user. The login process seems to be working fine, and I'm receiving the expected response from the server. However, I'm facing a couple of issues with the console.log statements inside the request.onload function and session storage.

Here's the relevant code for my user_login function:

```
function user_login() {
    var jsonData = new Object();
    jsonData.username = document.getElementById("loginUsername").value;
    jsonData.password = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value;

    if (jsonData.username === "" || jsonData.password === "") {
        alert('All fields are required!');
        return;
    }

    console.log("Payload:", jsonData);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "linkk/users-login", true);

    request.onload = function () {
        console.log("Response Status:", request.status);
        console.log("Response Text:", request.responseText);

        // Parse the response directly without try-catch
        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log("Parsed Response:", response);

        if (request.status === 200) {
            // Successful login
            console.log('Login successful. User data:', response);

            // The following lines for session storage don't seem to work
            sessionStorage.setItem("username", response.username);
            sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response));
            alert('Logged in successfully.');
            // You can also redirect the user to another page here
        } else {
            console.log('Login failed. Invalid credentials.');
            alert('Error. Unable to login.');
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        alert('Request error occurred.');
    };

    request.ontimeout = function () {
        alert('Request timeout occurred.');
    };

    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}
```

Issue 1: The problem is that the console.log('Login successful. User data:', response); statement inside the request.onload function is not displaying in the console, even though the "Logged in successfully" alert shows up. However, all other console.log statements outside the if condition work perfectly and display the expected data. This seems to be related to asynchronous behavior.

Issue 2: Additionally, I'm trying to use session storage to store the user's data (e.g., response.username and the entire response object). However, the data is not getting stored in session storage as expected, despite the successful login alert showing up.

For reference, here's the example of the response received from the server:

```
{
    "password": "hashed_password_1",
    "user_id": 1,
    "username": "user16",
    "favorite_games": [3, 2, 1],
    "reviews": [
        [2, "AMAZING GUY!"],
        [3, "chill dude"]
    ],
    "email": "user1@gmail.com",
    "gallery": ["imagelink1"]
}
```

I tried to log the response object inside the request.onload function using console.log('Login successful. User data:', response); to ensure that the data is being received correctly from the server.

I expected to see the response object logged in the console with the user's data, including the username, favorite games, and reviews.

However, when I checked the console, I noticed that the console.log statement inside the if condition (console.log('Login successful. User data:', response);) did not display any data, while all other console.log statements outside the if condition worked as expected.

Additionally, I attempted to store the user's data in session storage using sessionStorage.setItem("username", response.username); and sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response));, but it seems that the data is not getting stored in session storage, as it doesn't persist when I check it later.

The "Logged in successfully" alert is displayed, indicating that the login process is successful, but the absence of logged data and the session storage issue are puzzling.